# ClassNotFoundException when deserializing Serializable object through Intent from Android

Tags: java, android, serialization, serializable

I have two Android Application A and B. For the App A. I have a Serializable Object

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
public String[] var1;
public ArrayList<Integer> var2;

public MyObject (String[] var1, ArrayList<Integer> var2) {
    this.var1= var1;
    this.var2= var2;
}
```

Then, I send the instance of this class through Intent to another activity in App B by using

```
Intent i= new Intent("appB.component");
i.putExtra("myobject", fc);
startActivity(i);
```

In App B, I create the same Serializable class in App A. I try to get this but I got `java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = appA.MyObject )`

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();               
MyObject o = (MyObject) b.getSerializable("myobject");
```

Do we have a way to change the reference of the class in app A to app B, or manual way to parsing this object while do not modify the code in app A.

Answer (score 0):

Well `appA.MyObject` and `appB.MyObject` are not the same class.
One can't be deserialized into the other.

You would be better of to use GSON or a library like it to serialize your `appA.MyObject` class to JSON, send the resulting String through the Intent, and then deserialize the JSON String back to the `appB.MyObject` class.

Alternatively you could try to give both `appA.MyObject` and `appB.MyObject` a

```
private static final long serialVersionUID
```

field and set both UIDs to the same value. But I am not sure if that works.

A word of advice from the [Android Serializable documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable):

> **Implement Serializable Judiciously**
>
> Refer to Effective Java's chapter on serialization for thorough coverage of the serialization API. The book explains how to use this interface without harming your application's maintainability.
>
> **Recommended Alternatives**
>
> JSON is concise, human-readable and efficient. Android includes both a streaming API and a tree API to read and write JSON. Use a binding library like GSON to read and write Java objects directly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! The problem is very easy when I can use JSON. The thing is I just have some snapshot of the App A source code, and I can't modify it. So, I need to adapt my App B to address this problem. This sound crazy but may be feasible.  Do you think ClassLoader or ObjectOutputStream can handle this problem?

Comment: The problem is that your serialized binary is not a 1-to-1 exact copy of the object's source. It just contains the field names, values of these fields, and metadata that tells the ClassLoader where to look for the `.class` file to instantiate. This metadata will contain the fully qualified name of the class of the serialized object. So during deserialization the ClassLoader will look for a `.class` file inside an `appA` package and will not find anything because that package doesn't exist in your `appB` application.

Comment: So the only way I could imagine this might work, is if you give your `appB` the exact same package signature as your `appA`. So if the package signature of one object is `com.yourcompany.appA.MyObject` your appB.MyObject signature would also have to be `com.yourcompany.appA.MyObject`. Which I'm not even sure is possible. For more on the binary format of a serialized object see this: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html . Might be slightly different on Android but I doubt they changed the core concept.

Comment: Hi, the approach is very simple, you just create the second package in App B with the same name with the package in App A and create the class. Then, in the activity of app B, just import and use it like normal.